# IE9 not properly creating a select box with optgroup in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

When creating a select box manually IE9 doesn't work. It doesn't throw and error as far as I can see and nothing renders.

```
<select id="attributes" data-bind="value: value, valueAllowUnset: true" class="form-control">
   <!-- ko  foreach: groupedAttributes -->
      <optgroup data-bind="attr : { label: name }" label="default">
        <!-- ko foreach: things -->
          <option data-bind="text: name, disabled:disabled, value: $data"></option>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </optgroup>
   <!-- /ko -->
</select>

JS
var vm = {
  value: ko.observable(),
  groupedAttributes : [
    {
      name: "thing 1",
      things : [ { name: "test1", disabled: false},{ name: "test2", disabled: false} ]
    }, 
    {
      name: "thing 2",
      things : [ { name: "test3", disabled: false}, { name: "test4", disabled: false} ]
    }
  ]
}; 
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Works on Chrome and FF.

[See JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/kasesu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Any thoughts?

Comment: try accepting the answer which will be useful to someone in furture .

Answer (score 1):

Well we can fix this by avoiding usage of `containerless` conditional statements

**Modified View :**

```
<select id="attributes" data-bind="value: value, valueAllowUnset: true,foreach:groupedAttributes" class="form-control">
    <optgroup data-bind="attr : { label: name },foreach:things" label="default">
        <option data-bind="text:name,value: $data"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(value)"></div>
```

Working fiddle up **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25311/)**

**PS:** Tested in IE 8+,Chrome,Firefox .

Answer (score 1):

IE9 does not allow any other child elements in a `<select>` other than `<option>` and `<optgroup>`; this includes comments. IE9 (also IE8) strips out all other content long before Knockout can evaluate any bindings, so by the time KO wants to apply the bindings the comments are already gone.

You will have to go with either the `options` binding or use the `foreach` binding on the `<optgroup>` element itself:

```
<select id="attributes" data-bind="value: value, valueAllowUnset: true,foreach:groupedAttributes" class="form-control">
    <optgroup data-bind="attr : { label: name },foreach:things" label="default">
        <option data-bind="text:name,value: $data"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(value)"></div>
```

Comment: So related question(and was why the containerless bindings were used in the first place), placeholder text. The proper way is to add a default option where the value is undefined. If the select tag contains the foreach binding, I can't think of a way to add a default option outside the group.